# Python - Run two functions over and over again, parrallel to one another

Tags: python, multithreading

Lets's just say for simplicity that I have two functions - f1() and f2().
I want them to run simultaneously using Threading.
Also, when each one finishes I want it to start over again.

how would that be done?

Comment: Start a thread with a target function that calls f1() in a loop.  Start another thread with a target function that calls f2() in a loop.  You should probably have the threads check an event each loop iteration to see whether to keep looping or exit. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects